# How to get Vue v-for list rendering working with Blade view in Laravel

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm practicing Vue list rendering with Laravel, and can't get the data to display in my blade view with the v-for directive.

I've tried various examples from the Internet. I have a simple list with a few items that I want to display in a list, but instead of displaying the contents, I receive the item name displayed to the screen like {{ item.name }}

This is the relevant portion in my item.blade.php view file:

```
 <ul>
   <li v-for="item in inventory">
   @{{ item.name }}
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>


@section('scripts.app.footer')
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('js/app2.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

And this is from app2.js (don't need a .vue file yet since I haven't gotten to creating templates yet)

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
    ]
  }
});
```

All I'm getting in my browser is `{{ item.name }}` I would expect to see a list of the 4 item names. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, as I've looked at other examples and one of my other team projects is working just fine with v-for (using .js files, not .vue files), but I can't get a simple list to display. Any help would be appreciated. npm run dev is working fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data must return a data object `data:()=>{ return { a:'stuff' } }`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in inventory" :key="item">@{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      inventory: [
        { name: "MacBook Air", price: 1000 },
        { name: "MacBook Pro", price: 1800 },
        { name: "Lenovo W530", price: 1400 },
        { name: "Acer Aspire One", price: 300 }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9n5mz27km)